# Access Form - Current Records Count

Tags: function, ms-access, compiler-errors, vba, record

I created a public function, so that I could call it on Access forms, and display the result in a textbox control.  This is the public function:

```
Public Function CurrRecs(xRecName As String, frmName As Form, tblCount As String)
    If Forms(frmName).NewRecord Then
     frmName.txtCurrRec = "New " & xRecName & " Record"
    Else
     frmName.txtCurrRec = CStr(frmName.CurrentRecord) & " of " & _
     DCount("ID", tblCount) & " " & xRecName & "s"
    End If
End Function
```

This is what I have on the Form_Current()

CurrRecs("RecordType", "frmCurrentForm", "tblGetCountFromHere")

I get a compile error: Expected:=

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I realized I need to have the form listed as Forms!frmCurrentForm, but still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you're declaring `frmName` as a form, but using it as a string in one place, and a form in another

Also, if you want the table count, use `Form.RecordSet.RecordCount`, not an elaborate `DCount`

Rewritten:

```vb
Public Function CurrRecs(xRecName As String, frmName As String)
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = Forms(frmName)
    If  frm NewRecord Then
     frm.txtCurrRec = "New " & xRecName & " Record"
    Else
     frm.txtCurrRec = CStr(frm.CurrentRecord) & " of " & _
     frm.RecordSet.RecordCount & " " & xRecName & "s"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! I just got the same answer as I was working through the troubleshooting and researching declaring and setting forms.  Your solution is extaly what I did, except each place where it says frmName (ie frmName.txtCurrRec) it needs to now say frm.txtCurrRec.  Thanks!